# javascript update when screen resize

Tags: javascript, resize

I have some javascript being used which allows my nav's background to change colour dependent on how much the user has scrolled down. This works completely fine, however I am having an issue in finding a way that the java script updates every time the screen size changes, as at the minute I need to refresh the page on every re-size to make the anchor work correctly, as I believe some of the divs in between the anchor are based on percentage, therefore the height is changing every time the site re-size, but the javascript isn't reading that.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){       
       var scroll_start = 0;
       var firstchange = $('.anchor');

   var f_offset = firstchange.offset();

   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > f_offset.top) {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', '#fff');
       } 
       else {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', '#000');
       }

   });
```

Comment: did the answers below work?

Comment: No I couldn't get it to work unfortunately, it would just disable my function for some reason, it's just an annoyance if anything with this not working, as it leads to the site to be needing to refresh after every time the viewport is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the window to detect a change in screen size, which will then trigger a function when the window is resized.

See [jsfiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/4uxmeLLj/) showing how it works.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", winResize);

function winResize (){

    var scroll_start = 0;
    var firstchange = $('.anchor');
    var f_offset = firstchange.offset();

    $(document).scroll(function() { 
        scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_start > f_offset.top) {
           $('.nav').css('background-color', '#fff');
         } 
         else {
            $('.nav').css('background-color', '#000');
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: This might be needed for older versions of IE to work.(document).documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop;

Comment: @Sparky256 tbh I am not 100% sure. Feel free to edit the answer if you believe I am missing something out

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("resize", winResize);
```

function winResize (){

```
var scroll_start = 0;
var firstchange = $('.anchor');
var f_offset = firstchange.offset();

$(document).scroll(function() { 
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop? document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop();
    if(scroll_start > f_offset.top) {
       $('.nav').css('background-color', '#fff');
     } 
     else {
        $('.nav').css('background-color', '#000');
     }
 });
```

}

Comment: @Paul. I do not know if this is better, just that I use the same code (plus scrollLeft) to measure the scroll position of the page. For me it is just a diagnostic routine to test other routines.

Comment: I am not sure either, but both ways should still work based on what the user is asking! nice work :-)